# Transferring data with in workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

guys and gals i am stuck on this code that i have been working on it keeps erroring out saying that i have a next but not a for i only have two fors and two nexts. any help would be appreciated.

Sub TRANS2()

```
Dim wsCopy2 As Worksheet
Dim wsDest2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim inrow As Integer
Dim inmatch As String
Dim inpax As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim outrow As Integer
Dim outmatch As String
Set wsCopy2= Workbooks("CargoReport1.xlsx").Worksheets("CargoReport")
Set wsDest2 = Workbooks("w1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

If wsCopy2.Range("c2") > 0 Then


inrow = 1000


For i = 2 To inrow
    inmatch = wsCopy2.Range("d" & i)
    If inmatch = "" Then
        Exit For



outrow = 1000
    For k = 2 To outrow
        outmatch = wsDest2.Range("A" & k)
        If outmatch = inmatch Then
            Exit For
                End If

        If outmatch = "" Then
            wsDest2.Range("A" & k) = inmatch
                Exit For
                    End If
                        Next

        If outmatch = inmatch Then
                 Exit For
                    End If
                        Next

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TRANS2()

    Dim wsCopy2 As Worksheet, wsDest2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, inrow As Long, inpax As Long, outrow As Long, k As Long
    Dim inmatch As String, outmatch As String

    Set wsCopy2 = Workbooks("CargoReport1.xlsx").Worksheets("CargoReport")
    Set wsDest2 = Workbooks("w1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If wsCopy2.Range("c2") > 0 Then

        inrow = 1000

        For i = 2 To inrow
            inmatch = wsCopy2.Range("d" & i).Value
            If inmatch = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

            outrow = 1000

            For k = 2 To outrow
                outmatch = wsDest2.Range("A" & k).Value
                If outmatch = inmatch Then
                    Exit For
                End If

                If outmatch = "" Then
                    wsDest2.Range("A" & k).Value = inmatch
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k

                If outmatch = inmatch Then
                    Exit For
                End If
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Always indent your code. That way you can see what is missing. See this

```
For i = 2 To inrow
    inmatch = wsCopy2.Range("d" & i)
    If inmatch = "" Then
        Exit For
        outrow = 1000

        For k = 2 To outrow
            outmatch = wsDest2.Range("A" & k)
            If outmatch = inmatch Then
                Exit For
            End If

            If outmatch = "" Then
                wsDest2.Range("A" & k) = inmatch
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If outmatch = inmatch Then
            Exit For
        End If
    '~~~> SOMETHING IS MISSING HERE????
Next
```

You are missing and `End If` at `'~~~> SOMETHING IS MISSING HERE????` for `If inmatch = "" Then`

> this is before the inrow. If wsCopy2.Range("c2") > 0 Then i tried putting another end if where you commented that something is missing. but it did not like that – rubberduckiegod 5 mins ago

I think you are inserting it at the wrong place. This is your complete code

```
Sub TRANS2()
    Dim wsCopy2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inrow As Integer
    Dim inmatch As String
    Dim inpax As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim outrow As Integer
    Dim outmatch As String
    Set wsCopy2 = Workbooks("CargoReport1.xlsx").Worksheets("CargoReport")
    Set wsDest2 = Workbooks("w1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If wsCopy2.Range("c2") > 0 Then
        inrow = 1000

        For i = 2 To inrow
            inmatch = wsCopy2.Range("d" & i)
            If inmatch = "" Then
                Exit For
                outrow = 1000
                For k = 2 To outrow
                    outmatch = wsDest2.Range("A" & k)
                    If outmatch = inmatch Then
                        Exit For
                    End If

                    If outmatch = "" Then
                        wsDest2.Range("A" & k) = inmatch
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                If outmatch = inmatch Then
                     Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is before the inrow.   If wsCopy2.Range("c2") > 0 Then  i tried putting another end if where you commented that something is missing. but it did not like that

Comment: Works for me :) Are you sure you did exactly as I asked?

Comment: See the updated post, I have pasted your complete code... you may have to refresh the page to see it.